# xtrabackup --prepare and --apply-log-only question

Tags: mysql, backup, percona

I need to run the `--prepare` immediately after the backup with xtrabackup to make the backup consistent, or can I perform this step only when I am restoring the database? For example, running the `--prepare` 3 weeks later after the backup, before performing the restore.

If I'm using incremental backups as well, do I need to run `--prepare` with `--apply-log-only` additionally (together), or should I first run `--prepare` and then `--prepare --apply-log-only` to prevent the rollback phase?

IE: If I have incremental backups as well, should I do it?

```
xtrabackup --prepare --apply-log-only --target-dir=/backup/FULL_backup/

xtrabackup --prepare --apply-log-only --target-dir=/backup/FULL_backup/ --incremental-dir=/backup/incremental1_backup/

xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir=/backup/FULL_backup/ --incremental-dir=/backup/incremental2_backup/
```

or

```
xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir=/backup/FULL_backup/

xtrabackup --prepare --apply-log-only --target-dir=/backup/FULL_backup/

xtrabackup --prepare --apply-log-only --target-dir=/backup/FULL_backup/ --incremental-dir=/backup/incremental1_backup/

xtrabackup --prepare --target-dir=/backup/FULL_backup/ --incremental-dir=/backup/incremental2_backup/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make incremental backups, you *must not* do `--prepare` until you are ready to restore.

Think of it this way: after you use `--prepare` on a given backup, you can't make more incremental backups to it.

By analogy, it's like you're making a piece of pottery using fresh clay, and `--prepare` is like putting glaze on the pottery and putting it in the kiln to bake it. After it's baked, you can't put more fresh clay on that piece.